# Spring jpa combine two columns and order by one column and find top

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have table, where I need to fetch row based on two columns and find top records with the help of order by one column.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
id   product_id       sub_product_id         created_dttm
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1        1                2                   01-02-2021 07:03:25
2        2                1                   01-01-2021 08:03:25
3        1                2                   01-02-2021 09:03:25
4        2                1                   01-02-2021 08:03:25
```

in the above table, I have to get rows between `productid` and `subproductid`, order by `created_dttm`, to get last inserted records.

in spring jpa I am trying derived query as below

```java
public List<DailyStock> findTopByProductIdAndSubProductIdOrderByCreatedDttmDesc();
```

I want row id 3 & 4 to be returned as list

while executing above query, I am getting error

```
    expects at least 1 arguments but only found 0. This leaves an operator of type SIMPLE_PROPERTY for property productTypeId unbound.
```

Comment: I see the <sql> tag, but where's the SQL?

Comment: @jarlh This is a JPA question.  The "SQL" is baked into the method name `findTopByProduct...`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, will the answer contain any SQL? "_Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL._"

Comment: removed   sql tag

Comment: @pappu_kutty Could you please clarify what do you mean under `I have to get rows between productid and subproductid` ?

Comment: i meant, i want last inserted row for each combination of productid and subproductid

Answer (score 0):

You should add arguments to your method

```
public List<DailyStock> findTopByProductIdAndSubProductIdOrderByCreatedDttmDesc(
    Long productId,
    Long subProductId
);
```

I assume that both this columns are mapped to `Long` properties of `DailyStock` class

**UPDATE:**
If you don't want to pass any arguments you should rename your method to exclude columns from filtering query:

```
public List<DailyStock> findTopByOrderByCreatedDttmDesc();
```

Comment: but is there way without passing arguments?

Comment: this will get me last inserted record, but i need last inserted record for product id and subproduct id combined

Comment: @pappu_kutty but how will you tell DBMS to find records for product id and subproduct id  without substituting them into query? Just in theory